# Angular2: Stuggling to understand this strange behavior

Tags: angular

I have a WidgetComponent that I use in my Angular2 app.  The app is in fact two different apps within one:  a desktop version (boot-desktop) and a mobile version (boot-mobile).  The WidgetComponent I have already successfully used in the desktop version, and now I am working on the mobile version and I want to use the WidgetComponent in the mobile version.

However, I get this error when I attempt to utilize this WidgetComponent in the mobile version:

> browser_adapter.ts:78Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:538)
>       at zone.js:515
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:323)
>       at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.ts:67)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:322)
>       at Zone.run (zone.js:216)
>       at zone.js:571
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
>       at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.ts:56)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:355)

This error does not occur in the desktop version of the app.

So I tried an experiment.  I cloned WidgetComponent, ie created two identical versions of it - same code and mark up - as follows:

```
app/shared/widget
       widget.html
       widget.component.ts
app/shared/widget2
       widget.html
       widget.component.ts
```

Now, when in my mobile app I reference the widget component as follows:

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { WidgetComponent } from "./../../shared/widget2/widget.component";
// import { WidgetComponent } from "./../../shared/widget/widget.component";

@Component({
    directives: [WidgetComponent],
    selector: "some-component",
    templateUrl: "app/path/some.html"
})
export class SomeComponent {

    constructor() {}

}
```

IT WORKS!

But if I do the following, it DOESN'T WORK:

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
    // import { WidgetComponent } from "./../../shared/widget2/widget.component";
    import { WidgetComponent } from "./../../shared/widget/widget.component";

    @Component({
        directives: [WidgetComponent],
        selector: "some-component",
        templateUrl: "app/path/some.html"
    })
    export class SomeComponent {

        constructor() {}

    }
```

I am really baffled as to what is going on here.  Any ideas?

Comment: So if you say both versions are identical (which I doubt), just use working version :)

Comment: @dfsq I am sure they are identical (I copy pasted from one directory to the other). But I tried your idea, referenced the "working" version, in both projects.  But again, it worked in one, and not the other.  [Head hitting desk now]

Comment: if they are both on the same app, you can't have them both with same class name. I can't find any docs on this for now. But, try changing the class name for one of them, e.g. `export class MobileWidgetComponent{...}`

Comment: "Cannot read property 'query' of null" means that dependency injection can't resolve some dependency. Either the type used for the constructor parameter or the provider is not (correctly) imported or not provided at all. The code in your question doesn't show any constructor with parameters therefore it's unlikely that this code causes the exception. `WidgetComponent` used in `directives: []`might cause the exception if there are issues with the import (not sure) .

Comment: Are you on Angular 2 RC4 or RC5?

Comment: this was with RC4.  am in process of upgrading to RC5